# What's an alternative to GWL_USERDATA for storing an object pointer?

Tags: windows, winapi, 32bit-64bit

In the Windows applications I work on, we have a custom framework that sits directly above Win32 (don't ask).  When we create a window, our normal practice is to put `this` in the window's user data area via `SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, this)`, which allows us to have an MFC-like callback or a tightly integrated `WndProc`, depending.  The problem is that this will not work on 64-bit Windows, since LONG is only 32-bits wide.  What's a better solution to this problem that works on both 32- and 64-bit systems?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28VS.85%29.aspx) was created to replace [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28VS.85%29.aspx) in these instances.  It's LONG_PTR parameter allows you to store a pointer for 32-bit or 64-bit compilations.

```
LONG_PTR SetWindowLongPtr(      
    HWND hWnd,
    int nIndex,
    LONG_PTR dwNewLong
);
```

Remember that the constants have changed too, so usage now looks like:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, this);
```

Also don't forget that now to retrieve the pointer, you must use [GetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
LONG_PTR GetWindowLongPtr(      
    HWND hWnd,
    int nIndex
);
```

And usage would look like (again, with changed constants):

```
LONG_PTR lpUserData = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
MyObject* pMyObject = (MyObject*)lpUserData;
```

Comment: Right. And the LONG_PTR can be used to store data to a Window (very practical in many cases) as an integer or a size_t (as large as the OS pointer) to store a value like an int (by casting), if one do not want to allocate a memory (and free) to point at, and an int is enough. It is about the same as the SetWindowLong in 32-bit, but then (in the past) you needed to convert the long into a pointer to point at allocated data. And a pointer in 64-bit system might be longer than a long, so this change is an improvement because we can cast it to whatever we like.

Answer (score 12):

The other alternative is SetProp/RemoveProp (When you are subclassing a window that already uses GWLP_USERDATA)

Another good alternative is ATL style thunking of the WNDPROC, for more info on that, see

- http://www.ragestorm.net/blogs/?cat=20
- http://www.hackcraft.net/cpp/windowsThunk/

Comment: The problem with thunking (at least per the article) is that it's processor dependent as it relies on low-level assembly - article addresses x86 only; and the OP's question is about a different architecture. There's little good reason to chose a processor-specific technique when a processor-neurtal one is available: Get/SetWindowLongPtr works on both 32-bit and 64-bit compiles.

Comment: @BrendanMcK IIRC the windows link control uses GWLP_USERDATA so if you subclass it you need to store your data somewhere else. Yes thunking is CPU specific, see http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=4572.0 for a x64 version (Was unable to find any examples back in 08 IIRC)

Comment: (Ah, this is another one of those old answers that somehow appeared as 'new' on the RSS field due to a recent edit...) Yup, I agree with the first part of the answer; Get/SetProp is the way to go when subclassing. Still little reason to use assembler when there's an API that works. (Perhaps in a few years time the code would need to be changed to add an ARM version too!)

Comment: @BrendanMcK ARM is going to be WinRT only AFAIK. The reason to use thunking is performance; mov+jmp is faster than anything else...

Comment: ...and I'd question as to whether perf is really justified in many of these cases; anyone thinking that perf might be an issue would really need to measure first before resorting to assembler. I'm sure there are legit uses for thunks, but IMO they seem to be justified in only a tiny minority of cases; so would be extremely cautious about recommending them over APIs that are more readable, robust and maintainable.